# Родительный падеж и единственное число от слова "угги"

Tags: морфология

Как известно, угги — это разновидность мягких сапог. А как правильно образовать от этого слова родительный падеж: угг или уггов? А один — угг?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словарях этого слова пока не видно. Можно предположить, что оно будет вести себя так же, как слово сапоги (то есть как парные предметы: один угг, пара угг (нулевое окончание в Р.п.). В интернете встречаются только эти варианты. Думаю, что краткость названия вряд ли склонит нас к употреблению окончания ОВ.